# how to make it more quickly run scirpt when click on unity launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher

I put a script(with desktop file) on unity launcher. when I click it, the icon twinkle for a few seconds, during this period, I can not click it anymore.

So I want I can quickly run it twice, if I can setup something to reduce this period?

Comment: You could always add it to the launcher twice, and click the second one immediately after the first one. :)

Comment: Though it's strange, maybe you're right.